# Could not download docker image from docker hub

Tags: docker

Im using mac machine.OSX version is 10.11.3
Im trying to download an image from docker hub using dockerquickstart terminal.
I tried

## docker login

## docker pull myrepo/myimage

Im getting following issue;

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myrepo/myimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: The error is explicit, the image:tag that you’re attempting to pull does not exist or you don’t have access to the repository.

Comment: where do you expect the image to be located? dockerhub, other registry?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you don't have permission to pull this image. or the image you are trying to pull is does not exist anymore. try to pull another image and see you get the same error.